# Docker compose creating import errors?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, pytest-django

I am trying to run a simple django app on docker-compose I created a docker file and docker compose and when running I get the following.

I had two venv folders which I deleted cause they were a mess in GitHub.

I also have a submodule import which is some blockchain related stuff but it is just there and doing nothing at the moment within the django app

```
ahmed@Ahmed-PY:~/ssa2$ sudo docker-compose up
Recreating ssa2_web_1 ... done
Attaching to ssa2_web_1
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | 
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | May 17, 2022 - 14:39:40
web_1  | Django version 4.0.2, using settings 'ssfa.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
web_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 46, in get_internal_wsgi_application
web_1  |     return import_string(app_path)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
web_1  |     return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
web_1  |     import_module(module_path)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "/code/ssfa/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
web_1  |     application = get_wsgi_application()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
web_1  |     return WSGIHandler()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
web_1  |     self.load_middleware()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
web_1  |     middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
web_1  |     return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
web_1  |     import_module(module_path)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "/code/rframe/middleware.py", line 8, in <module>
web_1  |     from openfood_lib_dev.rpclib import sendtoaddress
web_1  |   File "/code/openfood_lib_dev/rpclib.py", line 5, in <module>
web_1  |     from slickrpc import Proxy
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slickrpc'
web_1  | 
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  | 
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
web_1  |     self.run()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
web_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 144, in inner_run
web_1  |     handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
web_1  |     handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 70, in get_handler
web_1  |     return get_internal_wsgi_application()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 48, in get_internal_wsgi_application
web_1  |     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
web_1  | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'ssfa.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

### The Dockerfile and docker compose file is as following

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

### The following is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: Is the required PyPI package actually listed in your `requirements.txt` file?  If you `docker-compose run web pip list`, is it installed?

Comment: I get this now after making changes to docker-compose.yaml `Starting ssa2_runserver_1 ... done
Attaching to ssa2_runserver_1
runserver_1  | python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ssa2_runserver_1 exited with code 2`

Answer (score 0):

If your project structure is uncertain do this

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webrun:
    build: ./
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"


Dockerfile

FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./ /app
ARG ENV
WORKDIR /app
RUN if [ "$ENV" = "dev" ] ; then pip install -r requirements-dev.txt ; fi
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Make sure you have all the imports listed in requirements.txt uses pipreqs library if you want